# IDE with HTML closing tag highlighting similar to closing brace

Tags: html, ide, highlighting

Is there an IDE that highlights each HTML closing tag (as you highlight over the opening tag, for example), similar to how many IDE's highlight where the opening/closing braces are for functions and such?

Comment: Might want to make this a Community Wiki instead, as there's not a single definitive answer.

Comment: An IDE for which programming language? Or do you just want a HTML editor?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite many IDEs that can do that and it's only up to you which one will you choose.
For example I often use NetBeans and Eclipse for HTML+CSS and PHP, sometime VisualStudio (for ASP.NET). For very fast editing, or something small I use Notepad++. All of them supports highlighting closing and beginning tags when marked. Also Dreamweaver is good for HTML, but I prefer to use OpenSource or freeware software (except for Visual Studio, but Express editions are also available free of charge).

So as you can see there are many options. I have to say that Notepad++ is quite powerful tool, very hight customizable, but for bigger HTML projects I use NetBeans due to it's code completion, syntax highlighting and other useful tools.

Regards,
Ventus

Answer (score 1):

There is ***[NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)*** amongst many other for sure.

Comment: does notepad++ have syntax highlighting for html tags?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Studio does this as well, so I'm assuming Eclipse PDT has it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes lots, you can use notepad++, aptana if you have a better machine, pspad

if you can use aptana and add the ftp site so you can have full access of everything ;)